# What inputs to smart contracts can be maliciously modified by miners, beyond timestamps? Why isn't this caught by mining verification?

Tags: contract-design, security, trust

Are there other trusted inputs which miners could maliciously modify which still get accepted by blockchain verification?  I realize the timestamp can be modified in a small way to potentially modify the outcome for a malicious purpose.

Comment: A miner can reorder transactions within a block to give them arbitrary priorities.

Comment: @Ismael  But I suppose if there exists one or a small amount of malicious miners to reorder the transactions, "consensus" among the major would make any attach meaningless, right?

Comment: @Ismael  In general, since miner can execute transactions within one block in arbitrary order, isn't it becoming difficult to reach consensus? Sorry I just becomes confused about the logic behind...

Comment: @lllllllllllll It is allowed by the protocol to reorder transactions, as long as they follow the rules the block should be accepted by other miners to reach consensus. Reordering is a desirable property for honest miners they can prioritize transaction with larger fees.

Comment: @Ismael Thank you Ismael. So just want to make sure, say I have 10 miners, and only one of them is malicious. Even if the malicious miner can reorder the transactions to achieve certain attacks, still, since the other nine follows certain "benign" order, the major wins and hence the attack cannot succeed. Does it make any sense to you? Am I missed anything here? Thanks.

Comment: @lllllllllllll There's no "benign" or "malicious" order, all ordering are fine and valid. The front running attack consist on miner placing its own transaction before others so they will be processed first. If a contract benefit the first to send transactions then a miner has a important advantage, the contract has to be designed such that the order of transactions is not important.